# Why SVD matrix is orthogonal matrix?

Tags: matrices, svd

I am trying to understand Why SVD matrix is orthogonal matrix. Let define SVD as  A=UDV', I want to prove that U is a orthogonal matrix. I understand each column of U is the eigen vector of AA'. I also understand that since AA' is symmetric matrix so its eigen vectors are orthogonal. Then we can prove U'U=I. However, to be a orthogonal matrix, U should also have UU'=I. How can we prove UU'=I?

Comment: If $U'U=I$, then $U'=U^{-1}$ and so $UU'=UU^{-1}=I$.

Comment: Assuming $U$ is square!

Comment: @John B. Thanks. if U'U=I then UU'=I. If this is true, I have two more questions: 1)When we define orthogonal matrix, we can just say UU'=1. Why do we have to say UU'=U'U=I 2)If all rows of a matrix are orthogonal to each other, then its column are also orthogonal to each other. Correct?

Comment: 1) We don't. 2) Yes (if it is a square matrix). It seems that @DavidM knows a definition of nonsquare orthogonal matrix. What is it?

Comment: @JohnB Not the intended implication! For the reduced SVD (often just called “the SVD” in my experience), U will not be square and hence not orthogonal.